# Azure SQL Data Sync blocks changes to database made with AJAX

Tags: jquery, sql-server, ajax, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to use Azure SQL Data Sync to sync the data between my development and production databases, which are both hosted on Azure. The site promotes events, and each event has a page made from the data from the database. I also have an AJAX form built with jQuery that calls an API created with node, which allows an admin user to create, update, and delete events from the database. I have all of this working like I want it to, and I have a production site and a slot with a development version of the site that look at 2 different databases. So far, so good, I can update both databases with the AJAX form on the different sites.

The next step was to set up Azure SQL Data Sync so that I can keep both sites' databases in sync. The way I want this to eventually work is that a user can create/edit/delete an event page on the development site via the AJAX form and then show it to the manager, who approves it, at which point we'll sync the databases and push the new data to the production database. I would also like to be able to make small changes straight to the production site and have them also sync to the development database. Basically I want to have an approval step for big changes and an easy way to make small edits that don't need approval.

When I set up Azure SQL Data Sync, it syncs the first time just fine and if I use SQL Server Management Studio to edit a table on one of the databases and then sync them, it also syncs the changes as expected.

The problem is when I make a change with the AJAX form it is no longer saves the change to the database. I could make changes with the AJAX form before setting up Azure SQL Data Sync and if I delete the sync group I can make them again, but I need to be able to make changes with the form so that non-programmers can also edit the site.

I hope that explains my question well. Normally I'd paste code, but there is no code involved in setting up Azure SQL Data Sync, just settings on Azure. If there is code that you think would help or would like to see, please let me know and I'll post.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: In the configuration settings for Azure SQL Data Sync, what is the `Sync Frequency` set to?  Is `Automatic Sync` enabled?

Comment: @JohnKurlak `automatic sync` is not enabled, so the `sync frequency` is not set. I only want it to sync when I trigger it, because there will be times when I do experiments on the dev page that I do not want to go live.